# Service Mysql cannot start

Tags: mysql, laragon

I have following error when i start my laragon server in my computer.
[image]

Comment: Is this a default installation of MySQL? I'm wondering if you've set up the data directory to be in a different place considering that you're getting the `unable to create temporary file` on startup.

Comment: ya this is default installation . I have not changed anything during installation , just click next only.

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and type:

```
mysqld  --tc-heuristic-recover=ROLLBACK
```

Restart all services and it will be ok.

Comment: This worked for me to get mySQL to run. However, when I stop mySQL and select mariadb-10.1.41-winx64 I get the following message: Service MariaDB can not start. Reason: 2019-10-25 12:33:06 31108 [Note] C:\laragon\bin\mysql\mariadb-10.1.41-winx6...\mysqld(mysqld 10.1.41-MariaDB) starting as process 20436 ...